# Fourier trasformation of a integral differential equation

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform

I dont understand how I could proceed for the calculus of the Fourier Trasform $\hat f(\omega)$ (and its anti-transform $f(x)$, but forget about that for this moment)  of

$f'(x)= x + \int_{+\infty}^{-\infty}\;e^{-|x-y|}f(y)dy$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Convolution_theorem

Comment: tell me more!!!

Comment: With $g(x)=e^{-|x|}$ then ${\cal F}(f')= {\cal F}(x) -{\cal F}(f){\cal F}(g)$ where ${\cal F}(f')=iw{\cal F}(f)$.